# Why is common lisp's `set-difference` not working?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

So, I am trying to use `set-difference` in Common Lisp (sbcl) and it doesn't really work on lists of structures.

For example,

```
* varr ;; =>
(#S(VAR :V S) #:$K520)

* pm ;; =>
(#S(VAR :V +) #S(VAR :V S) #S(VAR :V Y) #S(VAR :V X) #:$K520)

* (set-difference pm varr) ;; =>
(#S(VAR :V X) #S(VAR :V Y) #S(VAR :V S) #S(VAR :V +))
```

The answer should be:

```
(#S(VAR :V X) #S(VAR :V Y) #S(VAR :V +))
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The default test is `EQL`.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work this is how to do it:

```
(set-difference pm varr :test #'equalp)
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding explanations for why the original code failed and why the new code works.